# How to use wp_http with https-pages?

Tags: plugins, http-api

I'm trying to get content from an other site of mine, using iFrame-less Reloaded (http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe-less-reloaded/) It uses the class `WP_http` but doesn't work with a page in `https`. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to look at the `sslverify` argument and modify the plugin to use this. See the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

> The 'sslverify' argument was added in Version 2.8 and will check to
>   see if the SSL certificate is valid (not self-signed, actually for the
>   site in the request) and will deny the response if it isn't. If you
>   are requesting HTTPS and and know that the site is self-signed or is
>   invalided and are reasonably sure that it can be trusted, then set to
>   false.